# How to pass ctx scope to an external function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this code, where im forced to keep the function checkIfMember inside the context to pass it as an argument to another function. Because otherwise, I can't call ctx. It works this way, but I would like to have the function checkIfMember separate, but the problem is that ctx will be undefined. How would I go about passing the context or something that will allow me to separate the function?

```
bot.command('raintest', async (ctx) => {
//check if an user has a member rank in the group
function checkIfMember(uid, cid){
    return ctx.getChatMember(uid, cid).then(data =>{
        if(data.status == "member"){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }).catch(err =>{
        console.log(err)
    })
  }

let chatid = ctx.message.chat.id
let myId = ctx.update.message.from.id
let message = ctx.message.text.toString()
message = message.split(" ")
let numberOfUsers = message[1]
let tipAmount = message[2]
let totalAmountToTip = numberOfUsers * tipAmount

if (tipAmount != undefined && numberOfUsers != undefined) {
    if (tipAmount == 0 || numberOfUsers == 0) {
        ctx.reply("Users or Balances can't be 0 ⛔️!!")
    } else {
        if (Number(numberOfUsers) > 10) {
            ctx.reply("You cant rain for more than 10 users ⛔️!!")
        } else {
            userCommon.userHasEnoughtBalance(myId,chatid, totalAmountToTip).then(res => {
                if (res) { //THERE I PASS CHECKIFMEMBER AS A FUNCTION
                    userCommon.returnMembers(chatid, checkIfMember,numberOfUsers).then(res => {
                        if (res[0] == false) {
                            ctx.reply("⛔️⛔️ There are only " + res[1] + " users in the system.")
                        } else if (res[0] == true) {
                            let tipedUsers = []
                            var userArray = res[1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject ctx into your function:

```
function checkIfMember(ctx) {
    return function (uid, cid){
        return ctx.getChatMember(uid, cid).then(data =>{
            if(data.status == "member"){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }).catch(err =>{
            console.log(err)
        })
    };
};
```

Now checkIfMenber is a function that returns a function.

Then, when you have to use it as a callback:

```
userCommon.returnMembers(chatid, checkIfMember(ctx),numberOfUsers).then...
```

Answer (score 2):

How about taking `ctx` as another argument of the `checkIfMember` function.

Example: `function checkIfMember(uid, cid, ctx) { ... }`

I think this should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `ctx` as an argument to a function:

```js
function checkIfMember(uid, cid, ctx){
    return ctx.getChatMember(uid, cid).then(data =>{
        if(data.status == "member"){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }).catch(err =>{
        console.log(err)
    })
}
```

or, you can `bind` the context to a function and use `this`:

```js
function checkIfMember(uid, cid) {
    return this.getChatMember(uid, cid).then(data => {
        if (data.status == "member") {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }).catch(err =>{
        console.log(err)
    });
}

const checkIfMemberWithCtx = checkIfMember.bind(ctx);
// Next you need to use it like this: userCommon.returnMembers(chatid, checkIfMemberWithCtx, numberOfUsers)
```

or you can use the decorator:

```js
function checkIfMember(ctx) {
    return (uid, cid) => {
        return ctx.getChatMember(uid, cid).then(data => {
            if (data.status == "member") {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }).catch(err =>{
            console.log(err)
        });
    };
}

const checkIfMemberWithCtx = checkIfMember(ctx);
// Next you need to use it like this: userCommon.returnMembers(chatid, checkIfMemberWithCtx, numberOfUsers)
```